# Provide subjectAltName to openssl directly on the command line

Tags: certificates, openssl, bash

Is it possible to provide a subjectAltName-Extension to the openssl `req` module directly on the command line?

I know it's possible via a openssl.cnf file, but that's not really elegant for batch-creation of CSRs.

Comment: I just developed a web based tool that will generate this command automatically based on form input and display the output. http://kernelmanic.com/certificate-request-generator-with-multiple-common-names-and-subject-alternative-names/

Comment: It isn't clear from what you have included how the output of your tool applies to the Question. Also, can you explain how your tool works (in case the link goes dead)?

Comment: Peter(editor): 'OpenSSL' is the name of the _project_ and its output as a whole, but 'openssl' all-lower is the name of the command-line 'utility' program relevant to this Q.

Comment: As of 2019 this answer should be the accepted one: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183973/143034

Answer (score 227, accepted):

As of OpenSSL 1.1.1, providing subjectAltName directly on command line becomes **much** easier, with the introduction of the `-addext` flag to `openssl req` (via [this commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/bfa470a4f64313651a35571883e235d3335054eb)).

The commit [adds](https://github.com/levitte/openssl/blame/43890d7fc963d8c5ec3084dcf6c6c20b5efcaa7f/doc/man1/req.pod#L603) an example to the [`openssl req` man page](https://github.com/levitte/openssl/blob/43890d7fc963d8c5ec3084dcf6c6c20b5efcaa7f/doc/man1/req.pod):

```
Example of giving the most common attributes (subject and extensions)
on the command line:

 openssl req -new -subj "/C=GB/CN=foo" \
                  -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:foo.co.uk" \
                  -addext "certificatePolicies = 1.2.3.4" \
                  -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out req.pem
```

The commit message itself is also helpful to understand what's happening:

```
 Add 'openssl req' option to specify extension values on command line

The idea is to be able to add extension value lines directly on the
command line instead of through the config file, for example:

    openssl req -new -extension 'subjectAltName = DNS:dom.ain, DNS:oth.er' \
                     -extension 'certificatePolicies = 1.2.3.4'
```

This has been merged into the master branch of the [openssl command on Github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl), and as of April 18 2018 can be installed via a git pull + compile (or via Homebrew if on OS X: `brew install --devel openssl@1.1`).

Note that if you have set the config attribute "req_extensions" at section "[req]" in openssl.cfg, it will ignore the command-line parameter

Comment: The `-addext` is convenient for creating signing requests, but the SAN still has to be added when the csr is signed, correct?  Openssl doesn't have the equivalent flag on the `x509` command, necessitating the use of a file.

Comment: @end-user: if you issue the cert (which is _not_ signing the CSR) with `openssl x509 -req -CA/CAkey` yes. If you isse with `openssl ca` it can be configured with `copy_extensions` to put the extensions from the CSR in the cert.

Comment: (necroed elsewhere) if you specify `-addext` and also have req_extensions in config, it **doesn't ignore** either; instead it creates _TWO_ attribute items with OID pkcs9.14, which clearly doesn't make sense, though AFAICS rfc2986 doesn't prohibit it (as rfc5280 _does_ for extensions in certs). `openssl req -text` only _displays_ the first, and since attributes is a SET and the tbs is DER-encoded, which set of extensions is first is determined in an arcane way that might as well be random. Other things using the CSR, like `openssl ca` with `copy_extensions`, are also likely to be confused.

Comment: To make sure the extensions added to the CSR using `-addext` are really added to the signed certificate you have to enable `copy_extensions = copy` in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

Comment: adding `openssl x509 ...  -copy_extensions copy` made this solution working for me

Answer (score 158):

Based on [link](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/cmd-line-and-subjectAltName-td47538.html#a47548) from DarkLighting, here's the command I came up with using nested subshells.

```
openssl req -new -sha256 \
    -key domain.key \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=Acme, Inc./CN=example.com" \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
        <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com")) \
    -out domain.csr
```

All one line:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=Acme, Inc./CN=example.com" -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com")) -out domain.csr
```

Example use:

```
user@hostname:~$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=Acme, Inc./CN=example.com" -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com\n")) -out domain.csr
user@hostname:~$ openssl req -in domain.csr -text -noout
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=US, ST=CA, O=Acme, Inc., CN=example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a8:05:50:86:49:98:c8:05:01:e9:50:18:7f:2f:
                    b4:89:09:29:d1:c1:58:d8:14:bb:58:1d:25:50:11:
                    bb:43:d8:28:03:a5:de:59:49:bb:d2:f7:d3:79:5c:
                    c6:99:2c:98:ff:99:23:8c:df:96:7c:ea:4b:62:2a:
                    a4:c2:84:f5:5d:62:7f:7d:c4:7c:e2:c3:db:e6:58:
                    03:c2:26:9d:02:da:bb:84:d9:11:82:fe:38:12:9b:
                    c7:b6:ff:b2:40:30:38:b1:44:d8:47:1d:43:4a:29:
                    58:6b:49:ec:33:d7:dc:a7:1b:90:05:3a:f5:e6:16:
                    98:08:5d:2d:7e:b4:ea:a2:a4:b1:84:89:f7:f1:c4:
                    67:a6:a1:06:70:dd:4e:6b:0c:f8:b5:9b:bc:3f:06:
                    ee:90:d6:86:29:52:d3:af:f6:d4:2f:c6:cf:4b:5a:
                    b8:cd:01:74:6d:5c:25:a8:02:1c:7c:e8:66:3d:46:
                    07:b1:9d:ef:cc:eb:90:b6:bf:7b:33:e0:5f:b2:9b:
                    e8:b4:12:67:2f:8d:0d:9b:54:9d:95:6e:09:83:cb:
                    f3:5b:1f:31:8e:3b:ca:4e:08:e0:40:c0:60:40:72:
                    dd:0d:3e:99:ec:7c:ac:c4:3c:ba:85:9d:d9:d9:6b:
                    02:2e:bf:a8:a3:02:1d:eb:c8:58:e3:04:b3:a5:f1:
                    67:37
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         a2:1d:1a:e8:56:43:e7:e5:c7:c1:04:c1:6a:eb:d5:70:92:78:
         06:c1:96:fa:60:e2:5f:3c:95:ee:75:ed:70:52:c1:f0:a7:54:
         d2:9f:4a:2f:52:0f:d4:27:d8:13:73:1f:21:be:34:3f:0a:9c:
         f1:2a:5c:98:d4:28:b8:9c:78:44:e8:ea:70:f3:11:6b:26:c3:
         d6:29:b3:25:a0:81:ea:a2:55:31:f2:63:c8:60:6d:68:e3:ab:
         24:c9:46:33:92:8f:f2:a7:72:43:c6:aa:bd:8d:e9:6f:64:64:
         9e:fe:30:48:3f:06:2e:58:7c:b5:ef:b1:4d:c3:84:cc:02:a5:
         58:c3:3f:d8:ed:98:c7:54:b9:5e:50:44:5e:be:99:c2:e4:03:
         81:4b:1f:47:9a:b0:4d:74:7b:10:29:2f:84:fd:d1:70:88:2e:
         ea:f3:42:b7:06:94:4a:06:f6:92:10:4c:ce:de:65:89:2d:0a:
         f1:0f:79:90:02:a4:b9:6d:b8:39:db:de:6e:34:61:4f:21:36:
         a0:b5:73:2b:2b:c6:7e:2f:f2:e5:1e:51:9f:85:c8:17:9c:1a:
         b6:59:b0:41:a7:06:c8:5b:f4:88:92:c9:34:71:9d:73:f0:2e:
         31:ae:ed:ab:35:0e:b4:8a:9a:72:7c:6f:7a:3e:5d:66:49:26:
         26:99:e1:69
```

Comment: If your config is missing a `[ SAN ]` section, the `-reqexts SAN` section will result in the error message 'Error Loading request extension section SAN'. Incase anybody else runs into that.

Comment: I also had to set `-extensions SAN` to get this to work. Full 1-liner: `openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=Acme, Inc./CN=example.com" -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com")) -out domain.csr`

Comment: For a self-signed cert I needed `x509_extensions = SAN` in config file, for CSR -reqexts seems to work...

Comment: @GertvandenBerg For self-signed (meaning `openssl req -x509`) you can specify on the command line `-extensions SAN` and it works as well.

Comment: This oneliner only works in BASH (bash) not Bourne shell (sh), probably because of the sub-shell syntax.

Comment: Well, that's half the answer, but there seems to be something special you have to do when you create the cert, too. My CSR is coming out with a SAN section, but the cert is being created without it!

Comment: Bare in mind that this also creates a signing request, and not a certificate. And if signed improperly the subjectAltNames will get lost in translation.

Answer (score 68):

This is my solution to finally generate a working self signed cert, based on the answers above(The accepted answer don't work for me):

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -subj "/C=CN/ST=GD/L=SZ/O=Acme, Inc./CN=Acme Root CA" -out ca.crt

openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -subj "/C=CN/ST=GD/L=SZ/O=Acme, Inc./CN=*.example.com" -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com") -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt
```

`openssl x509 -in server.crt -text -noout`:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            ef:ca:cb:c7:3e:5c:25:85
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=CN, ST=GD, L=SZ, O=Acme, Inc., CN=Acme Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: May 15 14:42:17 2017 GMT
            Not After : May 15 14:42:17 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=CN, ST=GD, L=SZ, O=Acme, Inc., CN=*.example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:f0:19:32:51:9c:13:ec:dc:d4:52:30:d9:39:4a:
                    f5:9b:53:60:48:10:2d:c1:c0:48:ac:75:a3:2a:d2:
                    6c:62:f1:ed:39:46:7e:e7:e7:03:34:7a:c2:53:b7:
                    42:5a:f2:47:ff:34:68:b1:c9:28:3c:1c:eb:57:af:
                    90:87:53:85:3c:0f:6c:85:62:a1:02:94:b6:5f:3e:
                    e2:d1:bc:48:20:81:46:fe:25:b4:06:cd:b8:04:c4:
                    f5:81:f6:29:55:66:98:95:2f:db:75:39:82:7f:32:
                    5b:18:d9:9d:69:d0:f4:6b:0b:a2:92:83:b2:02:1b:
                    6c:d9:1e:f9:c4:f4:72:a6:76:e7:03:14:d6:29:2b:
                    be:e7:96:3e:42:3a:12:16:8b:51:11:22:7d:c1:d9:
                    47:ab:cd:93:36:27:d3:ad:af:85:0b:c4:d1:75:6e:
                    c1:a8:ed:f8:0f:4a:c8:79:21:4c:02:7f:27:70:00:
                    60:ed:68:8f:97:e0:0e:63:86:9f:12:07:78:aa:bf:
                    b1:bb:d1:30:ff:e6:7e:5c:cd:48:3b:31:fd:ab:54:
                    b4:af:dd:95:49:a6:17:0b:23:98:5f:3d:98:f2:eb:
                    8c:e4:aa:6e:44:2e:2d:5e:d5:91:a3:3a:61:18:3b:
                    56:29:47:86:1f:1d:d7:7c:6b:29:e7:ae:28:ec:3c:
                    e3:b1
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        56:d2:5b:d0:6a:d9:1d:0b:d4:2d:b3:99:cf:5f:92:e6:9f:4d:
        ea:b7:22:57:0b:85:e1:f7:4b:b1:13:c1:45:f7:7c:06:34:bd:
        0c:4b:e8:45:01:84:58:8a:7a:0d:7b:08:90:a0:91:7c:f1:f7:
        ef:de:3b:94:be:44:4b:71:c5:40:6f:3c:35:3e:61:79:b1:46:
        d9:81:31:bf:11:15:6a:b2:53:b9:a3:d7:81:cd:2d:f5:3e:20:
        dc:06:1c:a0:74:16:9f:d4:53:5d:f2:3a:23:1c:43:2d:ce:8b:
        68:d3:35:f3:36:8a:05:13:34:a7:42:75:6e:df:a2:b5:95:77:
        71:99:ae:be:4a:6c:ae:14:b4:d1:e4:f7:b4:39:b0:30:04:57:
        8a:d8:21:c5:1c:50:f3:86:38:ec:eb:0c:a6:f6:94:f3:f4:af:
        ec:1b:d1:79:ad:16:45:bc:c9:10:2a:a8:2d:b8:cf:7d:8a:aa:
        b4:b5:74:e0:d4:53:82:b5:71:b8:bb:2f:d2:12:51:87:ab:f1:
        b6:dd:1c:24:b1:8b:36:05:83:29:ca:58:ba:6b:f0:83:cc:27:
        86:43:00:da:73:a0:d5:36:31:bb:e7:e5:1b:2f:c0:42:55:7b:
        b4:2e:57:4f:88:b4:cd:0d:d0:bf:a8:87:76:a1:1b:bc:e4:fc:
        31:ba:ee:04
```

---

Repro step for "The accepted answer don't work for me" (On OSX 10.12.4, with system openssl):

```
bash-3.2$ openssl genrsa -out domain.key 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
.........................................................................................+++
....................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
bash-3.2$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=Acme, Inc./CN=example.com" -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com")) -out domain.csr
bash-3.2$ openssl req -in domain.csr -text -noout
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=US, ST=CA, O=Acme, Inc., CN=example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:cd:a5:97:b2:1a:83:c6:1d:0e:78:1a:6f:ca:4c:
                    e6:e3:64:94:41:b8:fb:f3:4a:4c:56:8c:33:36:c1:
                    5d:10:25:f5:86:f5:14:c6:17:22:53:34:7b:16:52:
                    ea:f2:ac:bf:0d:09:7d:55:c8:16:ce:0e:f9:98:20:
                    aa:11:4e:bb:4d:75:b1:ed:1b:ca:37:82:f1:15:71:
                    56:ad:c0:be:40:b4:ef:f2:e6:a5:a2:3b:e3:a8:0c:
                    8b:38:3d:d5:41:1a:e8:92:f6:78:52:9f:35:c2:98:
                    a6:58:87:64:e6:d3:7e:a0:00:8c:d0:16:13:80:e9:
                    ee:81:aa:40:c7:1d:9d:fc:52:9a:50:7d:50:e6:ca:
                    20:38:89:12:7d:99:a0:68:ae:45:64:03:e0:00:3c:
                    30:b7:94:87:ab:de:51:90:73:6b:bc:48:c4:e8:47:
                    2d:0e:5a:d0:fb:b4:1b:cb:76:7b:05:70:1a:a8:03:
                    bc:35:38:70:b5:ca:07:43:d3:9d:66:8c:32:32:74:
                    7e:6f:61:e8:de:80:de:d9:fd:fc:27:d8:bb:fa:8c:
                    f9:94:42:c4:b8:e0:bb:24:8b:1f:71:5b:18:99:ca:
                    ac:42:3b:ed:d7:4d:5f:dc:79:8c:6c:fe:d1:df:44:
                    05:5f:1a:a7:bd:e8:1c:85:0c:70:fb:4e:29:62:a0:
                    e9:71
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        47:f3:82:ae:78:f2:19:76:05:e3:97:30:00:16:c5:9c:89:94:
        ef:b0:51:b0:cf:4a:93:81:7d:ee:94:25:9a:0a:9e:1f:7f:e0:
        d8:72:55:75:2d:ac:c3:f9:3a:74:b6:1f:1b:c3:f1:68:d4:66:
        72:89:ed:53:7b:09:da:35:eb:40:63:e6:6a:0f:9a:4f:6e:25:
        9f:63:df:bb:d6:00:77:c2:e7:d6:96:0c:50:58:01:c9:d1:ff:
        df:de:fb:19:fb:72:38:48:25:5d:b7:56:fb:eb:d7:41:f5:f6:
        d7:f7:4b:c7:07:4f:59:b4:b8:c3:d8:bf:c9:2c:07:5a:c3:0a:
        51:f8:02:4f:dc:de:2d:88:49:b7:6d:de:67:04:d0:78:6e:0f:
        96:d8:06:e4:73:4f:fb:ce:29:0f:1e:3a:1a:6e:3c:a5:f3:f1:
        68:3d:22:85:34:fa:f0:ad:f6:75:61:02:81:f1:c4:e3:69:2b:
        80:3d:05:39:c6:9d:72:66:2a:50:93:6c:79:5d:d0:33:42:cf:
        a6:68:6a:16:d7:dc:61:b4:c3:4e:01:ac:68:7c:77:29:d4:fe:
        0d:9d:34:0a:3e:73:02:27:12:a4:08:9c:b9:2e:3e:c8:3f:1d:
        91:33:3b:71:8f:24:6b:66:f5:c3:8a:d7:7b:fe:2d:7f:b4:6d:
        96:cf:52:74
bash-3.2$ openssl x509 -req -in domain.csr -signkey domain.key -out domain.crt
Signature ok
subject=/C=US/ST=CA/O=Acme, Inc./CN=example.com
Getting Private key
bash-3.2$ openssl x509 -in domain.crt -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            de:c5:cf:28:1f:33:6c:53
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=CA, O=Acme, Inc., CN=example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: May 15 15:30:07 2017 GMT
            Not After : Jun 14 15:30:07 2017 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=CA, O=Acme, Inc., CN=example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:cd:a5:97:b2:1a:83:c6:1d:0e:78:1a:6f:ca:4c:
                    e6:e3:64:94:41:b8:fb:f3:4a:4c:56:8c:33:36:c1:
                    5d:10:25:f5:86:f5:14:c6:17:22:53:34:7b:16:52:
                    ea:f2:ac:bf:0d:09:7d:55:c8:16:ce:0e:f9:98:20:
                    aa:11:4e:bb:4d:75:b1:ed:1b:ca:37:82:f1:15:71:
                    56:ad:c0:be:40:b4:ef:f2:e6:a5:a2:3b:e3:a8:0c:
                    8b:38:3d:d5:41:1a:e8:92:f6:78:52:9f:35:c2:98:
                    a6:58:87:64:e6:d3:7e:a0:00:8c:d0:16:13:80:e9:
                    ee:81:aa:40:c7:1d:9d:fc:52:9a:50:7d:50:e6:ca:
                    20:38:89:12:7d:99:a0:68:ae:45:64:03:e0:00:3c:
                    30:b7:94:87:ab:de:51:90:73:6b:bc:48:c4:e8:47:
                    2d:0e:5a:d0:fb:b4:1b:cb:76:7b:05:70:1a:a8:03:
                    bc:35:38:70:b5:ca:07:43:d3:9d:66:8c:32:32:74:
                    7e:6f:61:e8:de:80:de:d9:fd:fc:27:d8:bb:fa:8c:
                    f9:94:42:c4:b8:e0:bb:24:8b:1f:71:5b:18:99:ca:
                    ac:42:3b:ed:d7:4d:5f:dc:79:8c:6c:fe:d1:df:44:
                    05:5f:1a:a7:bd:e8:1c:85:0c:70:fb:4e:29:62:a0:
                    e9:71
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        02:71:7f:a5:8e:aa:7d:4b:0a:9d:54:8c:25:cb:b3:66:a3:22:
        c5:61:73:0c:c4:da:3b:ce:e8:4b:ec:ee:45:83:ca:db:e0:25:
        9b:a6:a3:c0:c9:7c:d9:76:a2:8c:38:38:b1:77:c7:84:33:03:
        b7:9a:cb:ff:bf:83:bc:7b:d8:4c:7e:c4:b3:8f:c5:23:22:75:
        67:d3:d6:5e:0e:bd:ef:0b:0f:6a:8d:f0:d3:20:8f:5a:cf:37:
        94:b7:8a:d9:b3:0e:99:31:4f:77:6f:89:33:c5:93:99:2e:8b:
        61:ad:84:17:af:b5:8e:1e:f0:4a:af:b1:90:c3:09:3a:d6:16:
        4b:1b:c4:6b:2e:22:7e:b1:7d:9b:3c:a9:3b:06:20:e2:37:14:
        8b:0d:da:c6:4b:e3:6e:83:9c:df:20:67:2e:d0:33:68:05:17:
        01:d5:5a:6f:51:b3:50:d7:73:10:73:c8:be:3b:de:e6:bd:28:
        60:6f:19:75:0c:05:16:37:4d:50:df:f4:bb:41:f0:65:ba:6f:
        7f:5c:56:27:ae:0e:18:0a:df:7e:d2:7b:93:db:40:d2:bb:e0:
        dc:b8:57:c7:08:07:37:e4:db:d4:09:b6:13:d7:22:e2:ef:6d:
        60:fa:3e:7c:f4:1f:0b:bf:26:f4:08:d0:39:cf:51:dd:bf:b1:
        0e:ee:46:d1
bash-3.2$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

Comment: Why is it your solution? Can you talk us through it?

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer, I posted this because it works for me. The accepted answer doesn't work for me with `openssl x509 -req -in server.csr`, am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, but *why* does it work for you? What part replaces the accepted answer and makes it work? Right now, it's just a wall of code.

Comment: Don't know why, I've added the reproduce step to the answer. The change is: I moved the `subjectAltName ` param from `openssl req` to `openssl x509` command, then it works.

Comment: The question was about creating a CSR (presumably for submission to a real CA) and the accepted answer does that. Your answer creates a self-signed cert with SAN but not a CSR with SAN, so it doesn't answer the question here although it does answer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate

Comment: dave_thompson_085 is right, but having this answer here clearly is useful for other people, me included. The question is about CSRs, but the title does not specify that. What I propose is that you copy or link to your answer from the question he mentioned, "Missing X509 extensions with an openssl-generated certificate" https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate

Comment: The main difference in this answer compared to the accepted one (which only deals with how to generate a CSR with subjectAltName) is that in this answer two certificates are generated. A Root CA certificate and a domain certificate. The Root CA acts as the issuer of the domain certificate.

Comment: also in this answer it is shown how to sign a csr so the result certificate contains SAN

Comment: and this answer does not read the entire openssl config file \o/

Comment: worked for me, ca openssl < 1.1.1

Comment: Works for me on openssl 1.1.1 (cygwin) for self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 52):

My solution was to pass `subjectAltName` via an environment variable.

First have this added to `openssl.conf`:

```
[ san_env ]
subjectAltName=${ENV::SAN}
```

Then set the `SAN` environment variable when invoking openssl:

```
SAN="DNS:value1,DNS:value2" openssl req -extensions san_env -subj "/CN=value1" ...
```

Note: the `-extensions san_env` parameter needs to be present when signing the CSR as well as when generating it. Therefore, for CA-signed CSRs add `-extensions san_env` to the `openssl ca` command as well.

Comment: I get this error message `Error Loading extension section san_env`

Comment: That's probably because the `SAN` environment variable was not set or was empty.

Comment: I don't think this works on macOS.  I tried it with the export and with the variable inlined like Anton suggests.  I end up with `4696151660:error:0EFFF068:configuration file routines:CRYPTO_internal:variable has no value:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.260.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/conf/conf_def.c:563:line 122`

Comment: Creating a new config section and passing `-extensions` to the command line didn't work for me. I just replaced `subjectAltName=email:copy` with `subjectAltName=${ENV::SAN}` in the existing sections and it worked. So `-extensions` was useless for me

Answer (score 30):

As of 2023, with OpenSSL ≥ 1.1.1, the following command demonstrates how to generate a self-signed certificate with SAN for `example.com` and `example.net`:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
  -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj '/CN=example.com' \
  -addext 'subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:example.net'
```

Here we are using the `-addext` option.

If you are stuck to OpenSSL ≤ 1.1.0, e.g. on Debian ≤ 9 or CentOS ≤ 7, you can apply instead a tiny hack via `-extensions` and `-config`. The following command is portable in the sense that we don't have to mess around with (or even know about) the location of the `openssl.cnf` file:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
  -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj '/CN=example.com' \
  -extensions san \
  -config <(echo '[req]'; echo 'distinguished_name=req';
            echo '[san]'; echo 'subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:example.net')
```

The trick here is to include a minimal `[req]` section that is good enough for OpenSSL to get along without its main `openssl.cnf` file.

Either way, don't forget to verify the contents of the generated certificate:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in example.crt
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366949/19163 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333325/20407

Comment: Well done, thanks for your multiple useful answers re: OpenSSL. This is really the only updated answer on this page in particular.

Comment: What is `-addext`? - my openssl (v1.1) doesn't know this option and it's not listed on the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl.html)...

Comment: @Marc Please have a look at the OpenSSL manual of OpenSSL version 1.1.1, which clearly explains the `-addext` option: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-req.html

Answer (score 13):

So I had a heck of a time getting this working right, and putting at all in Ansible. As Ansible's `command` module doesn't allow file-redirects (`<(...)`), I had to use a small `.cnf` file as a template, but it's all working now. Here's what I did to make it work:

**The san.cnf template** (generated for each CSR/CRT pair):

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = v3_req
x509_extensions    = v3_req

[req_distinguished_name]
commonName       = {{ common_name }}
emailAddress     = {{ ssl_certs_email }}
organizationName = {{ ssl_certs_organization }}
localityName     = {{ ssl_certs_locality }}
countryName      = {{ ssl_certs_country }}

[v3_req]
# The extentions to add to a self-signed cert
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
basicConstraints     = critical,CA:false
subjectAltName       = DNS:{{ common_name }}
keyUsage             = critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
```

**Some Variables**

These Ansible variables used in the following commands, but you can substitute as needed in your scripts:

```
ssl_certs_fields: "/C={{ssl_certs_country}}/ST={{ssl_certs_state}}/L={{ssl_certs_locality}}/O={{ssl_certs_organization}}/CN={{common_name}}/emailAddress={{ssl_certs_email}}"
ssl_certs_local_privkey_path:       The path to the Private Key
ssl_certs_local_csr_path:           The path to the CSR
ssl_certs_local_path:               The local dir for this PKI file set
ssl_certs_local_decrypt_cakey_path: A temporarily decrypted copy of the CA
```

key
    ssl_certs_local_caserial_path: The CA's serial numbering file
    ssl_certs_local_cert_path: The final generated certificate file.

**The CSR Generation Command**

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -subj "{{ ssl_certs_fields }}" 
-key "{{ ssl_certs_local_privkey_path }}"
-out "{{ ssl_certs_local_csr_path }}" 
-config "{{ssl_certs_local_path}}/san.cnf"
```

**Self-Signing the CSR to create the Certificate**

```
  openssl x509 -req -days {{ ssl_certs_days }}
  -sha256
  -extfile "{{ssl_certs_local_path}}/san.cnf"
  -extensions v3_req
  -in "{{ ssl_certs_local_csr_path }}"
  -CA "{{ ssl_certs_local_ca_path }}"
  -CAkey "{{ ssl_certs_local_decrypt_cakey_path }}"
  -CAcreateserial
  -CAserial "{{ ssl_certs_local_caserial_path }}"
  -out "{{ ssl_certs_local_cert_path }}"
```

**To Verify the Result**

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in {{ ssl_certs_local_cert_path }}
```

That should include a section that appears as follows:

```
        X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            3B:6E:E9:9F:B2:30:08:21:1C:C7:0D:4C:21:7A:B4:92:40:B6:71:98
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:FALSE
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            DNS:foo.bar.com
```

Comment: For complex stuff like this, the shell Ansible module should be used instead of command. It is not really elegant either way - but thank you for your template workaround, this certainly works too.

Comment: I have provided a solution using the Ansible shell module down bellow. If only it was easier to generate CSRs in a sane way (or had openssl at least have a better user interface)...

Answer (score 8):

The 2nd post in this [link](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/cmd-line-and-subjectAltName-td47538.html) says that it not possible to do that only from command line, but the [4th post](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/cmd-line-and-subjectAltName-td47538.html#a47548) in the same link provides a workaround using bash's ability of referencing data as if it was in a file.

Taking a further look into it, someone mentioned the *reqexts* parameter used to make additions to certificate request. This [blog](http://abautu.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/openssl-setting-up-custom-ca.html) uses bash's *env* as an approach to this.

But i'm just trying to help. Haven't tested any of this myself.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the solution using bash's command substitution ability. This way everything is contained in a single script.

Answer (score 3):

Tested for RHEL7 (creating a self-signed certificate with a SAN)

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -sha256 -keyout test.key -out test.cert -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN -subj '/CN=test.example.com' -config <(cat /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf; printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:test.example.com,DNS:test2.example.com")
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a one line command to create a CSR - worked perfectly with no conf files, but didn't generate a SubjAltName entry.  This version is what I was using [Using read -p to request FQDN](https://superuser.com/questions/1129221/openssl-req-new-with-some-default-subj-values)  I wanted this to work with a SAN entry as well - so here's a working solution.

There is a dependency on the version of openssl, needs to be at least 1.1.1. because you need -addext.

```
read -p "FQDN ?" CN; openssl req -new -key yourkeyfile.key -subj /C=GB/ST=county/L=city/O=company/OU=yourorg/CN=$CN -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:$CN" -out./$CN.csr
```

No messing with conf files this way.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem was to create and reference a temporary cnf file by appending my command-line-collected subjectAltName information.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this for creating self-signed certs for local testing, but also wanted to be able to pass multiple parameters for extensions, not just SAN. I discovered that doing multiple `-extfile` commands, just seemed to overwrite each other, and only the last `-extfile` value ended up in cert.

The solution was just to add more variables to the printf:

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 \
    -extfile <(printf "extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com") \
    -days 820 -in server.csr -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
```

That works fine, but our workflow was already generated certs by storing the command in a package.json file, and then running `npm run newcert`. Attempting to add `\n` to the printf just broke the command. The solution for this was to switch to using a lot of echos, along with explicitly defining an extension name.

- *Note: For running these as an npm script, you'll have to escape the double quotes, and line continuations can't be used.*

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout key.pem \
    -subj "/C=CN/ST=GD/L=SZ/O=Example/CN=example.com" -out server.csr

openssl x509 -req -sha256 -extensions v3_ca \
    -extfile <(echo "[v3_ca]"; echo "extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth"; echo "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com") \
    -days 820 -in server.csr -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Running `openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.pem` shows it worked:

```
     X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered, but I still struggled with getting this into an elegant 
and useful form to automate CSR generation.  The one liner is nice so I incorporated it into a routine that allows the subject alternative names as command arguments rather than values in a file also the flexibility to SAN or not to SAN.  Try it with one argument then with many.

```
#!/bin/bash

#san_cert.sh

# defaults =====================================================================
DOM=domain.com
O=My\ Company,\ LLC
L=Seattle
ST=Washington
C=US
OU=Operations
EMAIL=certalert

#basic checks and strings ======================================================
if [ -z "$1" ];then
    echo usage: $0 name1 optionalname optionalname ...
    echo example: san_cert.sh www web w3 exch mail
    exit
else
    CN=$1
    SUBJ="/C=$C/ST=$ST/L=$L/O=$O/OU=$OU/CN=$CN.$DOM/emailAddress=$EMAIL.$DOM"
fi

#clearing old files
rm $CN.$DOM.ssl_csr $CN.$DOM.ssl_key

#create private key ============================================================
openssl genrsa -out $CN.$DOM.ssl_key 2048


if [ $# -gt 1 ];then #test for arg count
    #build SAN string ==================
    A=($@)
    I=1
    while [ $I -lt ${#A[@]} ]
    do
        SAN="DNS:${A[I]}.$DOM$CMA${SAN}"
        CMA=","
        I=$[$I+1]
    done
    SAN="\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=${SAN}"
    #===================================

    #create SAN certificate signing request ====================================
    openssl req -new -sha256 \
    -subj "$SUBJ" \
    -key   $CN.$DOM.ssl_key \
    -out   $CN.$DOM.ssl_csr \
    -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf "$SAN"))
else
    #create Single certificate signing request =================================
    openssl req -new -sha256 \
    -subj "$SUBJ" \
    -key   $CN.$DOM.ssl_key \
    -out   $CN.$DOM.ssl_csr
fi

#verification ==================================================================
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in $CN.$DOM.ssl_csr
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered, but if anyone's still looking for a no-prompt,  cli-only method to create a self-signed root cert (without CAs or CSRs) and don't mind using Java `keytool`, here's an alternative:

#### Generate a PKCS12 keystore with `keytool`

```
keytool -genkeypair \
 -keyalg RSA \
 -keysize 3072 \
 -alias titan \
 -dname "CN=titan,OU=Engineering,O=Titan Corp.,C=US" \
 -ext BC:c=ca:false \
 -ext EKU:c=serverAuth \
 -ext "SAN:c=DNS:titan,IP:192.168.1.7" \
 -validity 3650 \
 -keystore server.p12 \
 -storepass s3cr3t \
 -keypass s3cr3t \
 -storetype pkcs12
```

#### Export Certificate and Key with `openssl`

```
openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -nodes -out cert.pem -passin pass:s3cr3t
openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out key.pem -passin pass:s3cr3t
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer by @Excalibur (btw. thank you for your work!)

I find this form a bit more suited for Ansible. It sidesteps the problems of the official module `openssl_csr` that is somewhat difficult to work with due to library dependency and version problems.

The following is an adaptation of a part of the script generation by @Excalibur. You don't need to create a file. This particular playbook outputs the certificate to stdin which you can show with (`ansible-playbook -vvvv <playbook.yml>`) or dump to a variable and output using the debug module.

The domain.key needs to be in the same directory as the playbook.

```
---
- name: Test CSR generation
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
  - country: 'US'                     # C
  - state: 'NJ'                       # ST
  - locality: 'Trenton'               # L
  - organization: 'ACME'              # O
  - organization_unit: 'IT'           # OU
  - common_name: 'host.example.com'
  - email_address: 'info@example.com' # emailAddress
  - add_subj_alt_name: 'IP:192.0.2.0' # without common_name, e.g. IP:2001:db8::1

  tasks:
  - name: Generate CSR
    shell: |
      STR="/C={{ country }}/
        ST={{ state }}/
        L={{ locality }}/
        O={{ organization }}/
        OU={{ organization_unit }}/
        CN={{ common_name }}/
        emailAddress={{ email_address }}"
      openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "$STR" \
      -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_req -config \
      <(cat <<<'
      [req]
      distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
      req_extensions     = v3_req
      x509_extensions    = v3_req
      
      [req_distinguished_name]
      countryName                         = {{ country }}
      stateOrProvinceNamecountryName      = {{ state }}
      localityName                        = {{ locality }}
      organizationName                    = {{ organization }}
      organizationalUnitName              = {{ organization_unit }}
      commonName                          = {{ common_name }}
      emailAddress                        = {{ email_address }}
      
      [v3_req]
      # The extentions to add to a self-signed cert
      subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
      basicConstraints     = critical,CA:false
      subjectAltName       = DNS:{{ common_name }},{{ add_subj_alt_name }}
      keyUsage             = critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment') -noout -text
    args:
      executable: '/bin/bash'
```

Answer (score 0):

`extfile` for IP SANs when signing CSR to CRT
https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-create-client-server-certificate/

```
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA selfca.crt -CAkey selfca.key -CAcreateserial --extensions v3_req -extfile server.req -out server.crt
```

Comment: Why extfile? How is this answer different from all the other answers that mention extfile? If the answer is in the link, please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the default openssl.cnf file and add the line below in the [req] section:

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
**req_extensions     = req_ext**
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert
```

Then, add the content below under the req_extensions section:

```
#req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request
[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1   = x.x.com
DNS.2   = x.x.com 
DNS.2   = x.x.com
```

---

Once the custom config file is created, explicitly specify this config file while creating a CSR:

```
req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout test.key -out test.csr -config openssl_custom.cnf
```

Link to my working modified openssl config file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LB26NdW13d4WggbaYwQXR7wnXd_pXed3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is: you need two separate sections for requesting and signing certificates.

In signing section, REMOVE subjectAltName specification altogether.

Then it'll pass from the request.

```
[ x509_server ]

basicConstraints = critical, CA:FALSE
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, emailProtection, clientAuth

subjectKeyIdentifier = ${x509_base::subjectKeyIdentifier}
#subjectAltName = ${x509_base::subjectAltName}

authorityKeyIdentifier = ${x509_base::authorityKeyIdentifier}
issuerAltName = ${x509_base::issuerAltName}

authorityInfoAccess = ${x509_base::authorityInfoAccess}
crlDistributionPoints = ${x509_base::crlDistributionPoints}


[ x509_server_req ]

basicConstraints = ${x509_server::basicConstraints}
keyUsage = ${x509_server::keyUsage}
extendedKeyUsage = ${x509_server::extendedKeyUsage}

subjectKeyIdentifier = ${x509_server::subjectKeyIdentifier}
subjectAltName = ${x509_base::subjectAltName}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shout out to Thiyagarajen's [solution](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/252575/286171)

**[Background]**
Was trying to generate CSR with adding in SAN

After few experiments, here's what I did after reading all useful solutions here and various sources.

If the OpenSSL configuration file is defined well, then we could use `-config myopenssl.cnf` without the need of `-reqexts` param.

##### First, you would need to create an OpenSSL configuration file `{your_name}.cnf`.

For example,
`nano myopenssl.cnf`

***Below is a template OpenSSL configuration file***

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = VA
L = SomeCity
O = MyCompany
OU = MyDivision
CN = www.company.com
[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.company.com
DNS.2 = company.com
DNS.3 = www.company.net
DNS.4 = company.net
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = 127.0.0.2
```

##### Once you have configured well your `{your_name}.cnf`, let's proceed to generate the CSR

// Generate Certificate Signing Request(CSR) using existing key without creating a new key

```
openssl req -new -key myworker.key -out myworker.csr -config myopenssl.cnf
```

// Generate CSR with "new" RSA 2048 key

> -nodes is no DES

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out myworker.csr -keyout myworker.key -sha256 -config myopenssl.cnf
```

---

Based on my current understanding, I will try my best to explain the above configuration.
Please correct me if I'm wrong ~

#### Under [req] section,

1. `distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name` 
    First, we need to understand what **distinguished name** is? 
    [Distinguished Name](https://knowledge.digicert.com/generalinformation/INFO1745.html) (DN) is a set of values entered during enrollment and the creation of a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) such as:

   - C= Country (2 character country code such as US)
   - ST = State (must be spelled out completely such as New York or California)
   - L = Locality/City
   - O = Organization (legal company name)
   - OU = Organizational Unit (division or department of company but this is an optional field)
   - CN = Common Name (the fully qualified domain name such as [www.digicert.com](http://www.digicert.com))

So, `distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name` will point the OpenSSL to find the set of values under [req_distinguished_name] section and there's no need for us to use `-subj` param.

2. `req_extensions = v3_req` 
    Will point to [v3_req] section, whereby you could define any of the extension attributes you wish to add, in our case is just the `subjectAltName`. So, we could take out the `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage` attributes. So, there's no need to use `-reqexts` anymore to point to the SAN section when you define "req_extensions = v3_req" and at which you subjectAltName resides in this [v3_req] section!(When generating a CSR, like this, 'req' could use the commandline option -reqexts or straight from the defined configuration file entry req_extensions.)
3. `prompt = no` 
    Will not prompt you to enter the Distinguised name like usual, instead it will used the one configured inside this cnf file [req_distinguished_name] section.

#### Under [req_distinguished_name]

From the OpenSSL commandline return message,

> `What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.`
>
> `There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank`
>
> `For some fields there will be a default value,`
>
> `If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.`

However, from my testing, it seem like could not leave country (C) with '.', else will hit error like:
`140027926083488:error:0D07A098:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too short:a_mbstr.c:151:minsize=2`

***Below is a sample snippet of leaving blank for the distinguished name.***

```
[req_distinguished_name]
C = MY
ST = .
L = .
O = .
OU = .
CN = .
```

#### Under [v3_req]

We could either define subjectAltName in just one line like the upvoted solutions given in this thread or we could point subjectAltName to a "section" we created as shown in the template OpenSSL configuration file shown above.

**Either** 
`subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com,IP:10.0.0.1,IP:10.0.0.2`

**Or**

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.com
DNS.2 = www.example.com
IP.1 = 10.0.0.1
IP.2 = 10.0.0.2
```

#### Under [alt_names]

IP address must be in range of 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255

For example, when defining IP.1 = ip1, the returned error message would be like:
`139870375749536:error:220A4076:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:bad ip address:v3_alt.c:476:value=ip1`

For example, when defining IP.1 = 128.56.256.43, (invalid IP addr), the returned error message would be like:
`140205462144928:error:220A4076:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:bad ip address:v3_alt.c:476:value=128.56.256.43`

**Reference**:

1. https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX227983/how-to-create-a-csr-and-key-file-for-a-san-certificate-with-multiple-subject-alternate-names