# Generate X509 ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, x.509

I am trying to set up https server on python3, but I could not generate a certificate and a key properly.

That is the server code:

```
import http.server, ssl
server_address = ('localhost', 4443)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,
                               server_side=True,
                               certfile='cert.pem',
                               keyfile='key.pem',
                               ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is how I generate the certificate:

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem
```

I set **Common Name** to `mysite.com`

Then I made a record in `hosts` file, so that I could resolve my host by name:

```
127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
```

And import the certificate to the **trusted root CA section** in `*.pem` and `*.crt` formats

But chrome browser keeps showing an error

> "ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID", "Subject Alternative Name missing"

[image: Chrome certificate errors]

Is there something I missed or misunderstood?

Answer (score 3):

**Use SAN** or a different browser.

The SubjectAlternativeName extension identified in the error dialog, abbreviated SAN and also called UCC = Unified Communication Certificate by Microsoft and some CAs, has been the officially preferred place to identify your server for about a decade, superseding the use of CommonName (CN) as done last century. A few months ago, Chrome (at version 58) began *requiring* SAN and rejecting CN-only; other browsers don't for now, but may well follow suit in the future.

Especially if you want to use one cert for both `mysite.com` and `www.mysite.com` definitely use SAN. SAN allows you to have one cert for both of these; CN does not. Even if you use a wildcard `*.mysite.com` in CN it matches `www.mysite.com` and `multipedal.site.com` but NOT `site.com`; there are numerous Qs on this issue (search for them).

See https://serverfault.com/questions/845766/generating-a-self-signed-cert-with-openssl-that-works-in-chrome-58 
or https://serverfault.com/questions/880804/can-not-get-rid-of-neterr-cert-common-name-invalid-error-in-chrome-with-self

For more on the 'trick' of creating cert with SAN in OpenSSL without putting it in your config, see
[Provide subjectAltName to openssl directly on command line](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line)
[Followup to one-liner to create cert request with SAN](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113484/followup-to-one-liner-to-create-cert-request-with-san)