# How to add AltName from csr file to crt file using "openssl x509 -req"?

Tags: certificates, openssl, certificate-authority, chrome, windows-10

I'm a webdeveloper and want to test my websites locally with a self signed SSL certificate.
Everything was working great until a few days ago, when chrome started complaining about a missing `AltName` property.

#### OpenSSL CA

I've created my own authority using:

```
openssl req
    -x509
    -sha256
    -new
    -out dev.root.ca.crt
    -keyout dev.root.ca.key
    -days 3650
```

#### CNF

I've created an `openssl.cnf` file by adding those values to the default ones:

```
[ CA_default ]
copy_extensions = copy

[req]
req_extensions = v3_req

[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = $ENV::ALTNAME
```

#### ALTNAME via shell

Then I use this command to generate a `.csr` and `.key` file:

```
set ALTNAME=DNS:dev.example.com

openssl req
    -newkey rsa:2048
    -out dev.example.com.csr
    -pubkey
    -new
    -keyout dev.example.com.key
    -sha256
    -config openssl.cnf
```

The generated `csr` file contains the alternative name as expected.

#### Altname does not make it from CSR into CRT

Then I use this command to generate the `.crt` and `.key` files:

```
openssl x509
    -req
    -in dev.example.com.csr
    -CA dev.root.ca.crt
    -CAkey dev.root.ca.key
    -CAcreateserial
    -out dev.example.com.crt
    -days 3650
    -sha256
```

But the alternative names are not present anymore in the generated `crt` file.

#### What now?

Do I need to add additional parameters to the `openssl x509 -req` command ?

Comment: Background for this: Chrome demands a `SubjectAltName` now. Details in developer blog here: https://textslashplain.com/2017/03/10/chrome-deprecates-subject-cn-matching/

Comment: thank's for the edit and additional link @StackzOfZtuff ;)

Comment: Dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate  (partly mine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using the '-extfile' parameter fixed it.

#### Additional config file

I have added an `openssl-ext.cnf` file containing:

```
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = $ENV::ALTNAME
```

#### Using '-extfile' parameter

And added that new config file to the openssl command [using the `-extfile` parameter](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:X509(1)#SIGNING_OPTIONS):

```
openssl x509
    -req
    -in dev.example.com.csr
    -CA dev.root.ca.crt
    -CAkey dev.root.ca.key
    -CAcreateserial
    -out dev.example.com.crt
    -days 3650
    -sha256
    -extfile openssl-ext.cnf
```