# Subject Alternative Name in Certificate Signing Request apparently does not survive signing

Tags: openssl, x.509

So I have been able to create a Certificate Signing Request with a Subject Alternative Name of the form `subjectAltName=IP:1.2.3.4` by following the recipe in [a previous](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91556/36641) (splendid) answer.

When I inspect that CSR with `openssl req -in key.csr -text` I can see a corresponding section:

```
Requested Extensions:
  X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
    IP Address:1.2.3.4
```

I then proceed to signing the CSR with a self-signed key like so:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial \
  -in key.csr -out key.crt
```

The resulting certificate (when inspected with `openssl x509 -in key.crt -text`) does not identify that section any more.

Is this just an artifact of display parameters or need I also instruct `openssl x509` that it should include the extension when doing its signing (and if so, how)?

I am using OpenSSL on macOS High Sierra (`openssl version` reports `LibreSSL 2.2.7`) and have not changed its configuration from the defaults. The keys will ultimately be used between Debian (Stretch) servers, so I could perform key generation there, if it helps in this context.

Comment: [This other answer on that same Q](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159537/39571) already has your solution, except without the unnecessary copying of the config file which `req -x509` ignores. Plus my link to https://security.stackexchange.com/q/150078 which explains your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following command apparently resolves the issue:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial \
  -extensions SAN \
  -extfile <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=IP:1.2.3.4")) \
  -in key.csr -out key.crt
```

It is the [same recipe](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line/91556#91556) as for `openssl req`, but with the two parameters `extensions` and `extfile` instead of `reqexts` and `config`.

This command was helpful for quickly confirming the desired outcome by printing the relevant section:

```
openssl x509 -in key.crt -text | grep "Subject Alternative Name" -C 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option that works well is to use the [`-copy_extensions` option](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html)
and the `-extensions san` option.

Typically, the certificate generation can look like:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ./certs/server.csr \
  -CA ./ca/server-ca.crt -CAkey ca/server-ca.key -CAcreateserial \
  -copy_extensions copy \
  -extensions san \
  -out ./certs/server.pem
```

It basically performs the same operations as the accepted answer, but has a couple of advantages:

- it is easier to read and understand than using subshells and multiple redirections
- It does not require you to know the contents of the SAN in order to construct the `printf` statement

Comment: Note this works only in 3.0 up (i.e. since 2021); there are many non-bleeding-edge systems still using 1.1.1 or some even lower, although as years pass this will change.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to put the SAN in CSR and then sign it without losing them, by doing the following.

Find the openssl.cnf

In Ubuntu

```
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

CentOS

```
/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
```

And uncomment the following under the `[ CA_default ]` section

```
copy_extensions = copy
```

Then you have to create some files (if you don't know where, try issuing the first cert, the error message will tell you where)

```
sudo mkdir /your/dedicated-ca/dir/newcerts
sudo touch /your/dedicated-ca/dir/serial
sudo echo 1000 > /etc/pki/CA/serial
```

If you want to have duplicate certs by subject
    sudo echo unique_subject = no >> /etc/pki/CA/index.txt.attr

Now try to issue a cert, but not using `openssl x509`, but `openssl ca`

```
   sudo openssl ca -cert /your/ca/certfile.crt -keyfile /your/ca/certfile.key -in yourweb.csr -out yourweb.crt
```

Worked like a charm for me.