# How to copy Subject Alternative Names in csr while signing a cert?

Tags: certificates, openssl

I already know how to add Subject Alternative Names (SANs) to a Certificate Signing Request and I know it's possible to manually add once again to a certificate which is similar to add SAN to csr using OpenSSL like this:

```
openssl x509 -req -extfile < (printf "subjectAltName=IP:xxx" -days xxx -in xxx.csr -signkey xxx.key -out xxx.crt
```

Is there a way to achieve this with CLI?

The key is copy_extensions. I'll try it. And this link explains it: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372393

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your question is about the use of a command line tool, not about information security. I therefore voted to migrate this question to [su], as you have better chances of getting an answer there.

Comment: Do you mean creating a CSR, or the 'signing' (really issuing) operation that _reads_ a CSR? For the former, dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line . Also to be clear, you can use a config file other than openssl.cnf, so you can modify the config file without modifying openssl.cnf; does that meet your requirement?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thanks for your reply. I have already read that link. I think my question like this. https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2016-January/002764.html.

Comment: The Subject of this question, then, doesn't match your actual question (based on that openssl-users link) - you want to *sign* the CSR purely CLI, not *generate* the CSR purely CLI.

Comment: That email is vague but is either about specifying SAN in the operation that issues the cert _from_ the CSR (such as the `x509 -req -signkey` you posted) _or_ copying SAN from CSR to cert, which is a different operation and covered by different Qs: see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate and maybe cross https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371997/creating-a-local-ssl-certificate .

Comment: @gowenfawr thanks, I realize that I didn't express it correctly.I'll edit it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for your reply. I' ll try to use the copy_extensions option.

Comment: Note `copy_extensions` only works with `ca` NOT with `x509 -req` and thus not easily for self-signed as you are currently doing with `-signkey` if that matters to you

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to specify a SAN in OpenSSL solely at the command line*.

FWIW, I wrote a wrapper that allows you to do that by dynamically generating a temporary openssl.cnf behind the scenes for you:  [one_genkey](https://github.com/gowenfawr/one_genkey)

> A script for creating Certificate Signing Requests from the CLI,
>   hiding the OpenSSL config file complexity.

---

*Per dave_thompson_085's pointer to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183973/3365), openssl 1.1.1 added an `-addext` option to `req` which will allow this.  The sheer ingenuity of contortions provided in all the other answers on that page are a testament to how big a pain this has been for all time leading up to openssl 1.1.1, and all those systems (*cough* RHEL) still languishing with something other than the head branch.

Comment: For CSR (NOT cert) 1.1.1 (2018-09) has `req -addext`; see the link in my comment on the Q.