# x509 restrict the intermediate CA to sign only end user certificates

Tags: certificates, openssl, x.509

I am trying to restrict the intermediate CA to sign only end user certificates. However, I am not able to do so.

Man page of **x509v3_config** says

> basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
>
> A CA certificate must include the basicConstraints value with the CA
> field set to TRUE . An end user certificate must either set CA to
> FALSE or exclude the extension entirely. Some software may require the
> inclusion of basicConstraints with CA set to FALSE for end entity
> certificates.
>
> *The pathlen parameter indicates the maximum number of CAs that can appear below this one in a chain. So if you have a CA with a pathlen
> of zero it can only be used to sign end user certificates and not
> further CAs*

**Step 1:** Create a self signed root CA - rootCA.crt

> openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 4096
>
> openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -out rootCA.crt

**Step 2:** Create a Certificate signing request using below configuration file.

> openssl req -new -config extension.conf -out intermediate.csr

```
[ req ]
 default_bits       = 4096
 default_md         = sha256
 prompt             = no
 encrypt_key        = no
 default_keyfile    = privkey.key
 distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
 req_extensions     = v3_req
 
 [ req_distinguished_name ]
 countryName            = DE
 stateOrProvinceName    = Bayern
 localityName           = Munich
 0.organizationName     = Test AG
 organizationalUnitName = Services
 emailAddress           = services.dept@test.de
 
 [ v3_req ]
 basicConstraints       = critical,CA:true, pathlen:0
 keyUsage               = keyCertSign
```

The CSR is generated now

**Step 3:** Now sign the CSR with self-signed root CA with support from extension file

> openssl x509 -req -in intermediate.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey
> rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -extensions v3_req -extfile file.txt -out
> intermediate.crt -sha256

file.txt

```
[ v3_req ]
 subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
 authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always
```

Now intermediate certificate is generated.

**Step 4:** Create one more intermediate certificate and lets call it **TEST** certificate - using sightly modified configuration file as below:

```
[ req ]
 default_bits       = 4096
 default_md         = sha256
 prompt             = no
 encrypt_key        = no
 default_keyfile    = privkey.key
 distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
 req_extensions     = v3_req
 
 [ req_distinguished_name ]
 countryName            = DE
 stateOrProvinceName    = Berlin
 localityName           = Berlin
 0.organizationName     = Dummy AG
 organizationalUnitName = Product
 emailAddress           = product.dept@dummy.de
 
 [ v3_req ]
 basicConstraints       = critical,CA:true
 keyUsage               = keyCertSign
```

Generate the CSR

> openssl req -new -config test.conf -out TEST.csr

Sign the CSR with **intermediate.crt** which should not be possible.

> openssl x509 -req -in TEST.csr -CA intermediate.crt -CAkey
> privkey.key -CAcreateserial -out TEST.crt -sha256

As per the **man** page of **x509v3_config**, signing of the TEST.csr should fail as it is not the end user certificate.

The pathlen is 0 in my intermediate certificate. So I shouldn't be able to sign the TEST.csr. What am I doing wrong here? Can some one please kindly explain?

Comment: Sounds like this is a crosspost of this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913857/x509-restrict-the-intermediate-ca-to-sign-only-end-user-certificates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you look at the cert you created in step 3 with `openssl x509 -text <intermediate.crt` you'll see it doesn't have *any* BC extension (nor KU either). This is because creating a cert with `openssl x509 -req -CA/CAkey` does not use any extensions (more exactly, *requested* extensions) from the CSR. See [Missing X509 extensions with an openssl-generated certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate) https://serverfault.com/questions/845806/how-to-issue-ssl-certificate-with-san-extension https://superuser.com/questions/862838/s-mime-for-mac-and-ios .

But even if you fix this, **OpenSSL mostly doesn't *check* the certificate when it does a privatekey operation**, except in the SSL/TLS protocol (which requires full checks). (And in one case, `smime|cms -encrypt`, it apparently doesn't check even on a publickey operation.) The man page might more accurately say a CA cert with pathlen=0 can only *validly* sign leaf certs, not other sub-CA certs: OpenSSL, with either `openssl ca` or `openssl x509 -req -CA [-CAkey]` will actually *sign* a cert that violates pathlen (or even CA=false!), but if you subsequently *use* that cert in most cases it will fail validation and be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

> The pathlen is 0 in my intermediate certificate. So I shouldn't be able to sign the TEST.csr. What am I doing wrong here?

openssl is the swiss-army knife of PKI. It will do whatever you ask it to. I often need "illegal" certs when testing applications. The fact that openssl is not a drama queen about this makes it my tool of choice for PKI testing.

---

So you have a cert chain

```
Root [pathLen: 1] --> Int1 [pathLen: 0] --> Int1 [pathLen: ?] --> EE
```

Yes, that cert is illegal because of the EE is `pathLen: 1` from Int1. Where you will see errors is not on issuance, but when you try to *use* this cert. Try putting that cert on a website (for example `openssl s_server` in front of a `python3 -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1` ). Try connecting to it with browsers. The browsers should throw cert errors (if they don't, open bug reports with the browser, you may even get a bug bounty since that would be a real security issue).