# Is there a reason why generating a root CA with `openssl req ...` (with no -x509) followed by `openssl x509 ...` doesn't copy/preserve extensions?

Tags: openssl

Is there a reason for not copying certificate signing request's (CSR) extensions over to certificate when creating a root CA the following way?

1. `openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -key ca.key.pem -out ca.csr.pem -addext 'basicConstraints=critical,CA:true' -addext 'keyUsage=critical,keyCertSign'`
2. `openssl x509 -req -in ca.csr.pem -signkey ca.key.pem -out ca.crt.pem`

I'm aware that the single command `openssl req -x509 ...` does copy extensions, just wondering why using the two commands above doesn't.

---

**Initial question:**

Related question:
[Missing X509 extensions with an openssl-generated certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate)

I know other methods exist (i.e the `openssl req -x509 ...`), but specifically for using two separate commands

1. `openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -key ca.key.pem -out ca.csr.pem -addext 'basicConstraints=critical,CA:true' -addext 'keyUsage=critical,keyCertSign'`
2. `openssl x509 -req -in ca.csr.pem -signkey ca.key.pem -out ca.crt.pem`

to create a CA. Is there really no way to preserve the extensions from the CSR?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing X509 extensions with an openssl-generated certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate). Also, the [documentation for x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html) is quite clear in this regard: *"Extensions in certificates are __not transferred__ to certificate requests and vice versa."*

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes, and that is under the "bugs" (sic) section of `openssl x509` man pages, so it seems that transferring extensions is something that is wanted/expected, but currently is not implemented. So I wondered if there was a roundabout way by combining flags.

Comment: @mentallurg I asked here because perhaps there is a good reason to not transfer the extensions, and this good reason would be related to security (i.e this is what PKI is for).

Comment: *"I asked here because __perhaps there is a good reason to not transfer the extensions__, and this good reason would be related to security ..."* - It would have been better if you then ask exactly this, but you did not. In general a CA should not blindly sign everything somebody has put into a CSR, but it should only include the things it expects there and which fit the purpose of the certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I changed the question. What you said ("in general a CA should not blindly sign everything somebody has put into a CSR") makes sense: since creating CAs is much less frequent than signing CSRs for leaf certificates which could come from anyone.