# Specify Subject Alt Names in OpenSSL CA

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl

I know you can use `-addext` with `openssl req.....` but, are you able to do that with `openssl ca....`? I would like to be able to add Subject Alternative Names with only one command without having to edit the configuration file.

Comment: What's the point in adding alternative names in CA certificates?

Comment: I'm using a CA to sign server/domain certificates, in most modern browsers if you don't have a Subject Alternative Name then it'll reject the certificate as invalid.

Comment: Dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-the-command-line : you can (set and) use an env var, or on Unix with some shells you can use process substitution `<( ... )` to create a temporary file

Comment: @Matthew I believe you misunderstand the SAN requirement. It is required only in end entity SSL certificates. CA certificates do not fall under this requirement.

Comment: I'm using `openssl ca` to sign domain certificates, as listed above. I'm not adding the Subject Alternative Names to the CA, but rather the end-entity certificates I am signing, as stated above. I want to know if I can add SANs in the command.