# openssl csr generation with basicConstraint=CA:False

Tags: openssl, csr

I would like to know how to use the -extensions parameter of openssl req command to generate a csr with basicConstraint=CA:False, Please not i do not want to use a ssl configuration file but to generate the csr with command line only without referring to a openssl.cnf file. Is this possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: Neardupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line (but basicConstraints has an s at the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... how to use the -extensions parameter of openssl req command to generate a csr with basicConstraint=CA:False

The `-extensions` parameter is not used at all when generating a CSR. It is used for generating certificate extensions when generating a certificate (when `-x509` option is given). For specifying request extensions the (i.e. for the CSR) the `-reqexts` option has to be used.

Up until OpenSSL 1.1.1 there was no way in the `openssl req` command itself to do what you want, i.e. not using a config file. Depending on the OS there might be a way though to "magically" create a config file on the fly and use it. For example in Linux with bash shell the following can be done:

```
$ openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem -reqexts bc \
  -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf; printf "[bc]\nbasicConstraints=CA:false\n")
```

OpenSSL 1.1.1 added the option `-addext` and now it can be written like this (thanks to dave_thompson_085 to point out):

```
$ openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem \
   -addext "basicConstraints=CA:false"
```

Comment: New in 1.1.1 is a commandline option `-addext` which can be used instead of a config section. Also, you've misspelled the first occurrence of `reqexts`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for pointing out `-addext` and the typo. I've fixed and extended the question.